# Which Gintama episode has this scene of child Gintoki looking back upward to the camera in the sunset?

Tags: gintama

I am looking for this moment in *Gintama* where child Gintoki is looking back and upward to the camera in the sunset with blades and ravens.

[image]

If someone can help like anything, season, story, episode.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually **the front/main cover of the DVD for *Gintama* Season 04 Vol. 8**.

It's not taken from any scene or episode, nor does have any background story.

---

References:

- [Gintama Fandom Wiki](https://gintama.fandom.com/wiki/Merchandise/DVD#Season_4)
- [Aniplex](https://www.aniplex.co.jp/gintama/1st/dvd/dvd04.html#d0408) (Japanese)